# Density Plot of Year and Value

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, density-plot

I simply cannot get a density plot for the following data set:

[A single y Varibale and corresponding year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2ZGJ.png)

I have tried copying code and simply modifying and i simply can't get it to work.

I need to look like below:

[Density Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66J3.png)

I need the X -axis to be years and the y- axis to be in millions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(tidyverse)


ggplot(data = density, aes(x = welfare)) +
  geom_density(fill = 'steelblue', color = 'black') +
  theme_economist()
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: Remove the commas and dollar signs from your values, and ensure the "welfare" column is numeric. Does that solve your issue? In future, it is expected that you run `dput()` on your data and copy the result into your question, make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: If you want to do a density plot as in your example, then your code seems to be right as it plot the probability density function of the variable welfare. so y axis shows the probability density and x is welfare. If you want to plot year vs welfare then you probably want to plot a different graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, how we could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
df %>% 
  mutate(welfare_num = parse_number(welfare)) %>%
  mutate(year = ymd(paste(year, 1, 1, sep="-"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = welfare_num)) +
  geom_area(fill = "#63CB99", color = "#63CB99", alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar_format(prefix = "$", big.mark = ",")) +
  theme_economist()+
  labs(x = "YEAR", y="WELFARE")
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(year = 2013:2022, welfare = c("$388,866,936.62", 
"$726,076,253.19", "$1,266,141,639.47", "$987,167,047.54", "$1,392,749,702.19", 
"$1,335,220,815.50", "$1,819,630,833.96", "$2,359,170,587.39", 
"$3,283,576,817.91", "$3,668,277,476.93")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Tarjae! I took your example and tailored it to what I needed. T I learned a new element thanks to you (mutate); i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you misunderstood the concept of a density plot - your desired output is not possible with a density plot, which can only display one variable at a time (kind of like a histogram, it shows how the observations of a single variable are distributed).

My guess is: what your are looking for is essentially a line plot (or `geom_area` for fancyness). Line plots are good at displaying the relationship between two variables.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create reproducible example data
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(year = 2000:2023, wealth = runif(24))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = wealth)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.5, fill = "steelblue", color = "black")
```

[image: example area plot]

Comment: Your probably right, i spent hours trying to make it work before i came to you all. Most likely, its not the right plot for the job. You're correct, all i want to show is that area is gained welfare. Thank you!!